# building an XSLT string using variable in a foreach loop

Tags: xslt

The problem I'm facing perhaps simple for others, but being a beginner XSL - I'm yet to find a proper solution. What I want to do is build a string by concatenating the results of variables define in for-each loop.

Sorry it should be this:

```
<linked-hash-map>
<entry>
    <string>properties</string>
    <list>
        <linked-hash-map>
            <entry>
                <string>property_id</string>
                <int>123</int>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>type</string>
                <string>H</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>status</string>
                <string>CURRENT</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>description</string>
                <string>Test</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>lots</string>
                <list>
                    <linked-hash-map>
                        <entry>
                            <string>lot_id</string>
                            <int>123</int>
                        </entry>
                        <entry>
                            <string>lot_number</string>
                            <int>11</int>
                        </entry>
                        <entry>
                            <string>plan_number</string>
                            <int>100</int>
                        </entry>
                        <entry>
                            <string>plan_type</string>
                            <string>CC</string>
                        </entry>
                        <entry>
                            <string>plan_id</string>
                            <int>1</int>
                        </entry>
                    </linked-hash-map>
                </list>
            </entry>
        </linked-hash-map>
    </list>
</entry>
```

**Desired output**: SP - 31 - 108661

So basically I want to concatenate the *plan_type*, *lot_number*, and *plan_number* together into one string.

I've tried this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="linked-hash-map/entry/linked-hash-map/entry/list/linked-hash-map/entry" >
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- LOT NUMBER -->
        <xsl:when test="string[1] = 'lot_number'">
            <xsl:variable name="lot_number" select="int" />
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- PLAN NUMBER -->
        <xsl:when test="string[1] = 'plan_number'">
            <xsl:variable name="plan_number" select="int" />
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- PLAN TYPE -->
        <xsl:when test="string[1] = 'plan_type'">
            <xsl:variable name="plan_type" select="string[2]" />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>

<!-- LOT DETAIL -->
// concatenate string in here.
<xsl:value-of select="concat($plan_type, '-', $lot_number, '-', $plan_number)" />
```

But it doesn't work because of the variable being out of scope.
How can I achieve that desired output?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change as little as possible, try the following XSLT-1.0 code:

```
<xsl:template match="linked-hash-map">
    <xsl:variable name="plan_type" select="entry[string='plan_type']/string[2]/text()" />
    <xsl:variable name="lot_number" select="entry[string='lot_number']/int/text()" />
    <xsl:variable name="plan_number" select="entry[string='plan_number']/int/text()" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($plan_type, ' - ', $lot_number, ' - ', $plan_number)" /> 
</xsl:template>
```

Its result is:

```
SP - 31 - 108661
```

Comment: This works for me, just need to do some tweaking to the XSL code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that variables are local in scope to the block in which they are declared, so the each variable in this case would only be accessible within the `xsl:when`

But you don't need `xsl:for-each` or variables here. You can just do something like this (assuming you were in a template matching `linked-hash-map`

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(entry[string[1]='plan_type']/string[2], '-', entry[string[1]='lot_number']/int, '-', entry[string[1]='plan_number']/int)" />
```

Or maybe, to make it a bit more readable, separate out the lines

```
<xsl:value-of select="entry[string[1]='plan_type']/string[2]" />
<xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="entry[string[1]='lot_number']/int" />
<xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="entry[string[1]='plan_number']/int" />
```

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaGs/2

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing. Let me just add that `xsl:for-each` is not a loop. Each node is processed independently and you cannot pass values from one instance to another - certainly not by using a variable whose scope is limited to its parent node.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have an XSLT version number on the question, so I wondered what I would write in 3.0. Perhaps:

```
        <xsl:value-of select="for $n in ('plan_type', 'lot_number', 'plan_number') 
                              return entry[string[1]=$n]/*[2]" 
                      separator=" - "/>
```

Comment: The XSLT version would be 1.0

Comment: Yes, I guessed that - people who don't mention what version they are using often turn out to be using version 1.0. But since you didn't constrain the answer, it's a good opportunity to show you how much easier life would be if you moved forward.